# Bar chart labels in Chart.JS

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am creating a bar chart with 3 lines over it using the code below. I am trying to figure out how to get data labels to show on each of the bars and also 1 for each line (although I would settle for just on the bars. I have added the chartjs-plugin-datalabels to my project but cannot figure out how to use it. I am using chart.js v3.5.1.  Thanks for any help.

```
          this.chart = new Chart(this.myChart.nativeElement, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: 'Station Min.',
                  data: this.chartData.gen_min_data,
                  backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
                  borderColor: 'darkblue',
                  borderWidth: 0.5,
                  type: 'bar',
                  order: 4,                  
                },
                {
                  label: 'Target Min.',
                  data: this.chartData.target_min_data,
                  backgroundColor: 'green',
                  pointBorderWidth: 0,
                  pointRadius: 0,
                  borderColor: 'green',
                  type: 'line',
                  order: 3,
                },
                {
                  label: 'Max Available Min.',
                  data: this.chartData.max_min_data,
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                  pointBorderWidth: 0,
                  pointRadius: 0,
                  borderColor: 'red',
                  type: 'line',
                  order: 2,
                },
                {
                  label: 'Average Min.',
                  data: this.chartData.avg_min_data,
                  backgroundColor: 'orange',
                  pointBorderWidth: 0,
                  pointRadius: 0,
                  borderColor: 'orange',
                  order: 1,
                },
              ],
              labels: this.chartData.station_labels,

            },            
            options: {
              responsive: true,
              plugins: {  
                // plugin: [ChartDataLabels] , 
                legend: {
                  position: 'bottom',
                },
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: this.user.curDepartment + ' ' + this.chartData.dept_desc + '(' + this.fromDate + ')',
                  font: {
                    size: 20
                  }
                },
              },
              scales: {
                y:  {
                  display: true,
                  ticks: {},
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Minutes/Day',
                    font: {
                      size: 16
                    }
                  }
                } 
              }
            },
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

as described in the [documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration) you need to register the plugin first

```js
//Global register
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

//Per chart registration
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    // ...
  },
  options: {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello, I hope it's not too late, I have a similar case, I want to put the labels in stacked bars, I try to concatenate all the configuration of the graph to later pass it as an object to my html template that I use with handlebars. How do you think it could solve in my case? I using nodejs with express, I did a question about that